# Катеты, площадь и радиус треугольника

Tags: delphi

> Решите задачу через Delphi7. Прямоугольный треугольник задан гипотенузой и углом, прилежащим к ней. Найдите катеты, площадь треугольника и радиус вписанной окружности.

Comment: Подскажите формулы, по которым в школе решали данные задачи :) Честно, просто уже не помню. И далее, что Вам необходимо: консоль, гуи? Ведь дельфийский мир весьма обширен... И забыл спросить, преподы на антиплагиат проверять будут?

Comment: Да врядли будут проверять:)да честно говоря я вообще дуб в этом формулы щас напишу катеты: а=с*с-в*в, дальше аналогично,S=1/2*ab,R=2*S

Comment: чтобы проще объяснить,это 1 курс технического вуза

Comment: Сегодня вечером этим заниматься не буду - все-таки вечер :) Не закрывайте вопрос, скину завтра. А вообще - лучше бы выучили сами.

Comment: Пыталась учить и зубрить....ничего не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для гипотенузы с и угла alpha:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var a, b, c, r, s, alpha: double;
begin
  write('Enter c: ');
  readln(c);
  write('Enter alpha: ');
  readln(alpha);

  a := c * cos(alpha);
  b := c * sin(alpha);
  s := 0.5 * a * b;
  r := 2 * s / (a + b + c);

  writeln(Format('Results: a=%f; b=%f; S=%f; r=%f', [a, b, s, r]));
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Вот, а я радиус не помнил и сходу не догадался, как вывести формулу через площадь.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я могу вспомнить.

a,b - катеты; S - площадь; c - гипотенуза; alpha - угол (скажем между c и a).

Тогда

```
double a, b, c, S, alpha; // alpha в радианах

printf ("Enter c AND alpha (rad) > "); fflush(stdout);
if (scanf ("%f %f",&c,&aplha) != 2) {
    printf("Input error\n"); exit(1);
}
b = c \* sin(alpha); a = \* cos(alpha); S = a * b / 2;
printf ("a = %f  b = %f  S = %f\n",a,b,S);
// про радиус не помню
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;
Var
  a, b, c, Alpha, S, p, R: Extended;
begin
  Write('Gippotenuza: c = '); ReadLn(c);
  Write('Prilejaschii ugol: Alpha = '); ReadLn(Alpha);
a:=c * Cos(Alpha * Pi/180);
  b:=c * Sin(Alpha * Pi/180);
  S:=a * b/2;
  p:=(a+b+c)/2;
  R:=Sqrt((p-a) * (p-b) * (p-c)/p);
WriteLn('Katet 1 = ', a:5:3);
  WriteLn('Katet 2 = ', b:5:3);
  WriteLn('Ploschad = ', S:5:3);
  WriteLn('Radius = ', r:5:3);
WriteLn;
  WriteLn('=============================');
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Press ENTER!!!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```